# SumIfs in R - creating a subset off of multiple criteria and summing a specific column

Tags: r, sum, subset, sumifs

I have a set of panel data similar to:

```
city <- c("ARI", "ATL", "BAL", "BUF", "CAR", "ARI", "ATL", "BAL", "BUF", "CAR", "ARI", "ATL", "BAL", "BUF", "CAR", "ARI", "ATL", "BAL", "BUF", "CAR", "ARI", "ATL", "BAL", "BUF", "CAR")
week <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(city, week))
df$week <- as.numeric(df$week)
df$x <- c(6, 3, 9, 12, 4, 3, 7, 8, 2, 12, 15, 6, 3, 9, 0, 14, 18, 2, 21, 15, 17, 9, 10, 1, 22)
```

I would like to create a new variable, `df$y`, that sums `df$x` for each city, and for each week, prior to the week currently being observed. So, for example, `df$y[25]` should equal `31` because `sum(df[df$city == "CAR" & df$week < 5, 3])` equals 31.

My question is, how can I write this in a function to do this automatically?

To use `sum(df[df$city == "CAR" & df$week < 5, 3])` for each team and week combination would be tedious. My natural inclination is to write something like `df$y <- sum(df[df$city == df$city & df$week < df$week, 3])`, but that doesn't make sense. I'm new to R and don't fully understand functions; but, is that the best route for what I'm trying to do?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would never work anyway because you used `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` to create the data.  Your logical comparisons won't be accurate. You should use `data.frame()` to create the data.

Answer (score 0):

One option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% 
         group_by(city) %>% 
         mutate(y = cumsum(lag(x, default = 0)))
res[25,]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   city [1]
#    city  week     x     y
#   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    CAR     5    22    31
```

Answer (score 0):

One option with `data.table`

```
setDT(df)[, y := c(0, cumsum(x[-length(x)])), by = 'city']
df
```